# Cannot set UISearchBar's translucent property to NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, bartintcolor

I am trying to set the `barTintColor` of a `UISearchBar` without translucency. However, setting the `translucent` property doesn't seem to do anything. I have reproduced the issue in a [bare-bones Xcode project here](https://github.com/jamieforrest/SearchBarTranslucency).

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

The red color above is not the same as `[UIColor redColor]` in `UIViews` that are not translucent. I know about the workaround involving setting a background image on the search bar, but the above code should work as well.

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded your code and find solution for,  add one method name is `removeUISearchBarBackgroundInViewHierarchy` and set `searchBar.backgroundColor` as `redColor.`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;

    [self removeUISearchBarBackgroundInViewHierarchy:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void) removeUISearchBarBackgroundInViewHierarchy:(UIView *)view
{
    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            break; //To avoid an extra loop as there is only one UISearchBarBackground
        } else {
            [self removeUISearchBarBackgroundInViewHierarchy:subview];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a super hacky way to do it, but I confirmed it works.

Comment: I am waiting to see if anyone else comes up with something that doesn't involve removing private subviews.

Comment: Works well but sadly when the searchBar is focused, the status bar background becomes transparent instead of the original UISearchBarBackground color.

Answer (score 0):

Please set image in search bar like this it will solve your problem.

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red"]];
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to do it via `barTintColor`, not by setting a background image.

Comment: Ya but i have same issue i cannot get the same color which i want to display using barTintColor thats why applied above logic to get the exact result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late for the party,

However I've done a very simple and nifty extension for Swift 3 that allows you to use the translucent property without any trouble.

It involves no use of private API or dangerous walk-through within the object.

You can download it from this [Github repository](https://github.com/valvoline/UISearchBar-Translucent).